# Need a CoAP lib for Ionic Apps

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ionic5, coap

I am looking for CoAP client library that can be used for Ionic apps. Need to support both iOS and Android. I found this Cordova plug-in, but based on the docu it does not support iOS: https://github.com/houzdev/cordova-plugin-ccoap

Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe, you can give some more insights. I guess, the context is a javascript app running inside a web-browser. Why does that need a CoAP-client?

Comment: I have a mobile app that uses REST (HTTP GET/POST) to communicate with IoT devices via local network. The app is written in Ionic/Cordova. Now, I am looking for migrating from pure REST to CoAP, because CoAP provides a concept of subscriptions-instead of polling an endpoint with GET, the mobile app could just subscribe to it. I can implement 
CoAP on IoT devices - that's not a problem. But, I am looking for options how to let the mobile app talk CoAp. This plugin https://github.com/houzdev/cordova-plugin-ccoap may do the job, but it's not available for iOS.

Comment: You may check, if https://coap.space/impls.html helps. If you want to use RFC7641 (observe/notify), you need also to check, if that's supported by these libraries. And there are also http based techniques, which mitigates the "polling", e.g. delay the response for longer, if the change occurs, the device may use a pending request to response with that change in time.